# Unable to create new user in Splunk UI

Tags: splunk

I'm getting the below error when trying to create a new user in Splunk:

> Encountered the following error while trying to save: In handler 'users': Could not get info for role that does not exist: alert_manager

Do I need to disable any apps or delete the files related to any apps from the Splunk directory? Kindly suggest.

Comment: What version of Splunk are you using? Do you get this error when you try to create a user with a different role? Have you ever been able to create a new user?  Have you made any recent changes to the `alert_manager` role?

Comment: same here and apparently, it's quite recurrent in some case from a quick google search

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing any further information about your problem or environment, it sounds like the issue is with your `alert_manager` role, rather than a global issue.  Try to create a user with the `user` role (or another role) and see if that works; if it does, there is a problem with how your `alert_manager` role is configured (or that role doesn't exist).

To see how to modify or add roles, check out [Add and edit roles with Splunk Web](http://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/7.0.0/Security/Addandeditroles) in the Splunk docs.